# why does visual studio 2008 runtime require admin privileges, while 2005 and 2010 don't?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to copy the libraries from a computer that has them to one that doesn't without using the automated installer ?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Your title doesn't match your content.

Comment: **Just use the installer.** There is absolutely no reason *not* to. Note that you can also download an offline installer that doesn't require the target computer to have an Internet connection. **Please** don't just copy files out of the system directories, or you'll be back here in a week asking another question, this time impossible to debug unless someone goes back, reads the previous questions you've asked, and puts together the puzzle pieces.

Answer (score 0):

For the admin part no idea, for the automated installer part, I guess that if you just copy the DLLs in the same folder as the app EXE it will work just fine. I am not sure that this way is approved by MS though.

You'll find the DLLs in the c:\Windows\System32 folders (for VS2008 I guess msvcr90.dll and msvcp90.dll are enough).

Be careful, if you are on a x64 machine those will be x64 dlls, the 32 bits one are in SysWOW64).

You are not allowed to distribute the debug dlls (the one ending with a 'd' before the extension).